# Why is not this calculation correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel)

**CODE JS:**

```
    var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth();
    $('#main-content').css('overflow','hidden');
    console.log('latime:',windowsize);
    var stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
    console.log('stanga:',stanga);
    var dreapta= jQuery('.right').outerWidth();
    console.log('dreapta:',dreapta);
    var contentwh=windowsize-stanga-dreapta;
    $('#main-content').css('width',contentwh);
    var content= jQuery('#main-content').outerWidth();
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('width',contentwh);
```

My div `(#main-content)` must be exactly as the remaining space.

Unfortunately to me is slightly larger look at the picture below ...

[image]

What is wrong with this calculation?

Comment: Check it May be padding is applying on "main-content". Check with firebug(layout) and in Chrome(Computed).

Comment: the website link isn't working: error 500

Comment: Try setting `outerWidth(true)` to include padding and margin.

Comment: all elements to apply? (stanga,dreapta, windowsize)

Comment: I tried and nothing changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I got your Problem.

[image]

You haven't calculate padding of "secondary" div
So Calculation is like for secondary div is

```
 var stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth() + 30;
```

Hope this will solved your problem.

thanks.

Comment: if you put extra distance increases 30

Comment: I left padding removed from all secondary and not calculated well

Comment: Can you make it live your changes so I can check it?

Comment: In My PC 
jQuery('.right').outerWidth() = 432  
jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth() = 260  
jQuery('.row').outerWidth() = 1349  
So Main-Content = 657
  So it's looks good if you go width ".row"